# VM cannot resolve DNS of Azure WEB app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have web app in vnet with private DNS. When login to VM of same vnet, I should be able to open web app from VM.

Trying to open it I see something like this:
[image]

When try to resolve it with nslookup it doesnt reutrn IP.
[image]

This is how private endpoint DNS configuration looks like. I would say all as it should be.
[image]

Anyone now what should be the reason and how to fix this?

Comment: Is the private DNS Zone linked to the VNet? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-virtual-network-links

Comment: Yes, it is linked.

Comment: Please run 'ipconfig /all' on both the VM and WebApp consoles to ensure that both have private IP addresses and are using the same DNS server.

Comment: Cannot open Kudu to check on web app. When try to open I get same page as trying to open app.

Comment: The web app won't be actually running on the VNet unless it's an ASE.  Private Link just injects an IP in the target VNet.

Comment: You can check from portal, which Vnet & Subnet are assigned your private endpoint and VM.

Comment: Maybe will be helpful for someone, DNS server was on different subscription and that was the reason why dns zones I've created could not be resolved.